# Elasticsearch Aggregation on objects by query on other documents

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Lets say i have an index that contains documents that represent a Message in a discussion.
that document owns a discussionId property.
(it also has its own ID "that represent MessageId")

now, i need to find all discussionIds that have no documents (messages) that match a query.
for example: 
"Find all discussionIds , that have no message that contains the text 'YO YO'"

how can i do that?

the class is similar to this:

```
  public class Message
  {
     public string Id{get;set}
     public string DiscussionId {get;set}
     public string Text{get;set}
  }
```

Comment: discussion is a logical group of many messages.
the challange is to find a list of discussionIDs that doesnt contain a certain message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap the query that would find [matches for the phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) "YO YO" in a [`bool` query `must_not` clause](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

With NEST

```cs
client.Search<Message>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .MustNot(mn => mn
                .MatchPhrase(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Text)
                    .Query("YO YO")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which, with [operator overloading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/bool-queries.html#_operator_overloading), can be shortened to

```cs
client.Search<Message>(s => s
    .Query(q => !q
        .MatchPhrase(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Text)
            .Query("YO YO")
        )
    )
);
```

Both produce the query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text": {
              "type": "phrase",
              "query": "YO YO"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To only return `DiscussionId` values, you can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)

```cs
client.Search<Message>(s => s
    .Source(sf => sf
        .Includes(f => f
            .Field(ff => ff.DiscussionId)
        )
    )
    .Query(q => !q
        .MatchPhrase(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Text)
            .Query("YO YO")
        )
    )
);
```

And, if you want to get them all, you can use the [scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-scroll.html)

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<Message>(s => s
    .Scroll("1m")
    .Source(sf => sf
        .Includes(f => f
            .Field(ff => ff.DiscussionId)
        )
    )
    .Query(q => !q
        .MatchPhrase(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Text)
            .Query("YO YO")
        )
    )
);

// fetch the next batch of documents, using the scroll id returned from
// the previous call. Do this in a loop until no more docs are returned.
searchResponse = client.Scroll<Message>("1m", searchResponse.ScrollId);
```

Comment: it seems that these queries will return all messages that have no "YO YO" in the text.
but still, all discussions have many messages. some, have one message of "YO YO". so it means that in the query presented above, all discussions will be returned, 
did i understand your query correctly?

Comment: What does the `Discussion` type look like? Do you have that indexed as well? With a Parent/Child relationship between discussions and messages, you'd wrap the `bool` `must_not` in a `has_child` query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-has-child-query.html. Alternatively, you'd get a list of all the discussionids that contain "YO YO" and then feed that into a scroll in a `must_not` clause

Comment: seems like your first option with "bool must_not in a has_child" will do the trick.
i will add the discussion as a type to the index. (i tried to get a way from this, but seems like my only option).

Comment: The latter option will also work, but means you'll perform the operation in two phases - find those discussion ids that match and then get all messages that do not contain that discussion id. Having the `Discussion` type as a parent document or alternatively, having messages as nested types on a `Discussion` (if there aren't many messages in a discussion) may be better if it's common to look across a discussion as a whole.